# My react-native app launches fine in Debug mode, but when built Release, crashes on launch

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

If anyone could help I'd very much appreciate it.

I'm creating a react-native app, when the app launches in Debug mode it works just fine, when I launch it in Release mode, it builds, but when launched, crashes immediately.

There are no crash reports, I can get the log from my device, but it isn't very informative. It just seems to die during bootstrapping.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this before and/or have any insight?

I've tried
a) clearing caches
b) reinstalling node_modules/Pods
c) updating libraries
d) changing my Provisioning Profile
e) comparing to a blank react native app and going file by file to see if anything I had would break it

Here's the limited stack trace I was able to get from the simulator:
[image: simulator stack]

Thank you!

Update!
I've got a crash report!

```
Dyld Error Message:
  dyld: No shared cache present
Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[id]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[id]/[bundle]/[app]
  Reason: image not found
```

Another update for anyone who ever finds this:
I didn't figure out how to resolve this issue. I ended up creating a new blank react application using a template, then one by one moved my modified code back over. It's all working now. I'll leave this open if anyone has any insight on what was initially going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you try to open multiple time after sometime later you will get a popup report then view the error, Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Rashed, Thank you for your reply! I tried opening the app several times, none of which show any content, unfortunately. :[